# Flutter build error (No file or directory error "data/user/0")

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Im trying to build and run on my flutter to debug. But everytime I ran it, an error occurs. How do I fix this? note: the app dont require to login

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error says `no such file or directory`. You can confirm this by following:

```
var filePresent = await text.exists();
  if (filePresent) 
  {
    print('file present');
  } else {
    print('file not present');
  }
```

If it prints `file not present`, that means there's no file at the specified location and you need have that first.